# How to limit the nr of threads in a thread pool for infinite iterable?

Tags: python, multithreading

Suppose we want to iterate infinitely through all the natural numbers and open a thread for each number up to a limit. Since there are infinite natural number this list acts like a generator, so how can we keep a limit on the number of open threads while generating the numbers?

I'm trying something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(i):
    """ Do something with i"""

p = Pool(10)
i = 0
while True:
    p.imap_unordered(func,i)
    i += 1
```

I tried many other different ways (threadpools, semaphores, etc) but all of them seem to ignore the max nr of threads. I want to make something take opens up MAX_THREADS threads and everytime a thread finishes, it iterates again and start a new one. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You are already setting the maximum number of *processes* in your Pool. You are not using threads at all. What makes you think your setting is ignored and an arbitrary number of threads is spawned?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). The first parameter to the constructor is `max_workers`, which determines how many threads it can use.

So you end up with something like this:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n) as pool:
    future = pool.submit(function, *args)
future.result() # outputs result
```

The returned value is a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future), so you can access the result once the future is completed. When the `with` block ends, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` waits for all of its workers to finish, so you can safely access the results after the end of the block.

---

Here is a simple example of `ThreadPoolExecutor` in action:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def fn(delay, result):
    sleep(x)
    print(result)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
    pool.submit(fn, 3, "last")
    pool.submit(fn, 1, "first")
    pool.submit(fn, 1, "middle")
# This should output "first", then "middle", then "last"
```

Comment: I already tried that. I cant see the ouput of func anythere. it looks like it is iterating through the numbers infinitely

Comment: @GuilhermeLima `Executor.submit` returns a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future), so if you say `x = pool.submit(...)`, you can access the result as `x.result()` once the thread has completed its job. If you want the results to automatically populate a data structure, you could save them in a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) instead of returning them from the function.

Comment: i have some print statements inside the worker function and they are not getting printed. Whats going on?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima I can't be sure without more details, but I've added an example that works for me to my answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: I think the OP's main points are being able to process the numbers indefinitely and to schedule a new worker as soon as one finishes

Comment: @GuilhermeLima I think I see where my answer failed. You are dealing with an infinite iterator, so you need to start the new jobs only when an old one finishes, or it will try to put infinite jobs into the queue of upcoming jobs. The simplest way to deal with this is probably using [`Future.add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback) to start the new jobs once each finishes. However, this feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

One light solution using asyncio

```
import asyncio
import itertools as it
from random import randint


MAX_WORKERS = 5

async def worker(num):
    s = f"worker for {num}"
    print(s, "start")
    await asyncio.sleep(randint(1,2))
    print(s, "end")
    return num*100

async def main():
    seq = it.count()  # counts natural numbers endlessly
    pending = []  # the tasks which are pending
    while True:
        groups = zip(*[seq]*(MAX_WORKERS-len(pending)))  # fetching only as many inputs as the completed ones
        works = [
            worker(i) for i in next(groups)
        ]  # create as many workers as the ones which have completed

        # now await the completion of the first among the pending tasks and the new ones
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            it.chain(pending, works),
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
        )
        print("Done", len(done), "Pending", len(pending))
        for t in done:  # print the result of each task which has completed
            print(t.result())


asyncio.run(main())
```

produces, for example:

```
worker for 1 start
worker for 4 start
worker for 0 start
worker for 2 start
worker for 3 start
worker for 1 end
worker for 4 end
worker for 0 end
worker for 2 end
Done 4 Pending 1
100
400
0
200
worker for 5 start
worker for 8 start
worker for 6 start
worker for 7 start
worker for 3 end
worker for 8 end
worker for 6 end
Done 3 Pending 2
300
800
600
worker for 11 start
worker for 10 start
worker for 9 start
worker for 5 end
worker for 7 end
worker for 11 end
worker for 9 end
Done 4 Pending 1
700
500
1100
900
worker for 15 start
worker for 12 start
worker for 13 start
worker for 14 start
worker for 10 end
Done 1 Pending 4
1000
worker for 16 start
worker for 15 end
worker for 13 end
worker for 14 end
Done 3 Pending 2
1400
1300
1500
worker for 18 start
worker for 17 start
worker for 19 start
worker for 16 end
worker for 12 end
Done 2 Pending 3
1600
1200
worker for 20 start
worker for 21 start
worker for 19 end
Done 1 Pending 4
1900
worker for 22 start
worker for 18 end
worker for 17 end
worker for 20 end
Done 3 Pending 2
1800
2000
1700
worker for 23 start
worker for 24 start
worker for 25 start
worker for 21 end
worker for 22 end
Done 2 Pending 3
2100
2200
worker for 27 start
worker for 26 start
worker for 23 end
worker for 24 end
worker for 25 end
worker for 26 end
Done 4 Pending 1
2500
2300
2600
2400
worker for 30 start
worker for 31 start
worker for 28 start
worker for 29 start
worker for 27 end
Done 1 Pending 4
2700
worker for 32 start
worker for 30 end
worker for 31 end
worker for 28 end
worker for 29 end
Done 4 Pending 1
2900
3000
2800
3100
worker for 33 start
worker for 34 start
worker for 35 start
worker for 36 start
worker for 32 end
worker for 35 end
worker for 36 end
Done 3 Pending 2
3600
3500
3200
worker for 39 start
worker for 38 start
worker for 37 start
worker for 33 end
worker for 34 end
Done 2 Pending 3
3400
3300
worker for 40 start
worker for 41 start
...
```