# Convert a simple multithreaded program with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am still pretty new to Python asyncio, so I am trying to convert a simple problem I solved using multithreading, to using asyncio.

I made an example of what I want to achieve.
Each MiniBot instance can start at random times (those `time.sleep()` calls in main represent instantiations at unpredictable times.)

I am expecting each MiniBot to run in parallel if they start before others have finished.

All good with MultiThreading, but when I translated the problem with async coroutines, I can't get them to start together.

I could use `gather`, but this would require to have all the task at the beginning, which I don't.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Oh yes, I am using Python 3.6

**Multithreaded version**

```py
import threading
import time

class MiniBot(object):
    def __init__(self, _id:str):
        self._id = _id
        self.alive = True
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.th = threading.Thread(target=self.run)

        self.internal_state = 0


    def _foo(self):
        self.internal_state += 1


    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self._foo()

            if time.time() - self.start_time > 4:
                print(f"Killing minibot: {self._id}")
                print(f"Var is: {self.internal_state}")
                self.stop()
            time.sleep(0.1)


    def start(self):
        print(f"Starting Minibot {self._id}")
        self.th.start()


    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # MiniBots activities start at random times but should coexist
    MiniBot('a').start()
    time.sleep(2)
    MiniBot('b').start()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    MiniBot('c').start()
```

*Output:*

```
Starting Minibot a
Starting Minibot b
Starting Minibot c
Killing minibot: a
Var is: 40
Killing minibot: b
Var is: 40
Killing minibot: c
Var is: 40
```

**Async version (Not behaving as I hoped)**

```py
import asyncio
import time

class MiniBot(object):
    def __init__(self, _id:str):
        self._id = _id
        self.alive = True
        self.last_event = time.time()

        self.internal_state = 0


    async def _foo(self):
        self.internal_state += 1
        asyncio.sleep(2)


    async def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            await self._foo()

            if time.time() - self.last_event > 4:
                print(f"Killing minibot: {self._id}")
                print(f"Var is: {self.internal_state}")
                self.stop()
            asyncio.sleep(0.1)


    def start(self):
        print(f"Starting Minibot {self._id}")
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(self.run())
        finally:
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
            loop.close()


    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # MiniBots activities start at random times but should coexist
    MiniBot('a').start()
    time.sleep(2)
    MiniBot('b').start()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    MiniBot('c').start()
```

*Output:*

```
Starting Minibot a
Killing minibot: a
Var is: 2839119
Starting Minibot b
Killing minibot: b
Var is: 2820634
Starting Minibot c
Killing minibot: c
Var is: 2804579
```

Comment: You need to run the async loop. And use asyncio.wait with a timeout or create_task to launch each bot. BTW just launch all of them with gather and make them sleep initially. I would help you but I'm driving to work..

Comment: Thank you @Pynchia, but that doesn't solve it.
As I mentioned, I can't use `gather` because the number of MiniBots and the time when they need to start is unknown.
The main program starts and runs indefinitely, and when specific events happen, I launch a new MiniBot.

Comment: I think you should improve the quality of your question as I see you aren't satisfied by the excellent answer you got

Comment: If it helps, have a look at [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897259/how-to-limit-the-nr-of-threads-in-a-thread-pool-for-infinite-iterable/57901586#57901586) to a similar problem

Comment: If you are referring to your answer, in my question I had actually specified: 
"I could use gather, but this would require to have all the task at the beginning".
If you are referring to user4815162342's answer.. then it's another story

Comment: I guess the question is when do _you_ want the program to exit? Do you even want it to exit automatically at all, or do you want it to keep spawning minibots on external requests? (Servers tend to work like that, and include a `serve_forever()` method.)

Answer (score 1):

`start` cannot call `run_until_complete` because `run_until_complete` runs a coroutine through to the end, whereas you need multiple coroutines running in parallel. The asyncio equivalent of creating and starting a thread is [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), so `start()` should call that, and return to the caller, like in the threaded version.

For example:

```
import asyncio, time

class MiniBot:
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id
        self.alive = True
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.internal_state = 0

    def _foo(self):
        self.internal_state += 1

    async def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self._foo()
            if time.time() - self.start_time > 4:
                print(f"Killing minibot: {self._id}")
                print(f"Var is: {self.internal_state}")
                self.stop()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    def start(self):
        print(f"Starting Minibot {self._id}")
        return asyncio.create_task(self.run())

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False

async def main():
    taska = MiniBot('a').start()
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    taskb = MiniBot('b').start()
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    taskc = MiniBot('c').start()
    await asyncio.gather(taska, taskb, taskc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Don't let the call to `gather()` throw you off: `gather` simply gives back control to the event loop and returns when all the provided tasks/futures have finished. You can replace it with something like `await asyncio.sleep(10)` and have the same effect (in this example). And if you have an unpredictable number of futures, there are other other ways to signal the end-condition.

Also note that you need to await `asyncio.sleep()`, otherwise it has no effect.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.
One thing is still not clear to me: how can I use `gather` if the number of **MiniBot** I will start is unknown?

`main` starts and runs indefinitely, when certain events occur, a new `MiniBot` is created and launched.

Comment: @Uno `gather` is just a convenience function for the situations where you want to wait for a number of things to finish. If that is not the case, you can await on any other synchronization mechanism. For example you can create a stop event with `stop = asyncio.Event()` and end `main()` with `await stop.wait()`. That will block the main coroutine until the event is triggered (which may never happen), while allowing other coroutines to execute.